# Python Module for Analyzing User Response

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-analysis, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Is there any module available in Python which can help the developer in analyzing customer query and take action/respond accordingly.

For example,

1.)
Customer Query:   Can I have a hot coffee?
Scrip Response:    Sorry. We don't serve this item(hot coffee)

2.)
Customer Query:   Can I have a cold coffee?a
Scrip Response:    create_order_and_prepare_item("cold coffee")

The above example is completely irrelevant to my requirement. But idea is that I want to respond to the customer based on some certain keyword/behavior and then compare it with my local database traits/keywords.

The user will send an email and I am creating a bot for an automatic reply.   This will happen by a Python script which will run every few minutes and send the replies or may take some action of calling other scripts. This has to be an in-house script and we cannot afford to connect with the Internet and use external APIs.

Do you have any Python module suggestion which can suggest me a "response" by taking a look at available data of previous communication?

Comment: Do you really need AI? Or is a sort of command-line syntax OK? (meaning customers have to word their request in a particular way, for instance they can not say "*Hey get me another one like yesterday, but not damn boiling!*")

Comment: Hi @NicolasRaoul , Yes. that should also be good.   My users are expected to respond in a particular way and if my script is able to understand 80% of the requests correctly, then it has done a great job